# File.Exists("SDF File Path") returns a FALSE when run through Unit tests even though it exists in the Execution Directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I am writing Unit tests for a Windows Project. The Executable project on the Client Side of this Windows Project has a code **File.Exists("LanguageLookups.sdf")** which is used to check and return a **Bool** if the sdf file exists in the Execution Directory or not. But when i execute the same piece of Code through a Unit test; The code **File.Exists("LanguageLookups.sdf")** returns a FALSE. Its not able to find this SDF File. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the current working directory of the unit test using [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx). Your unit test runner most likely is not running your test with the same working directory as your Windows application, and therefore your unit test cannot find the file because it is looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: Hi Adrian,

Thanks a lot!!!!! I could solve this problem. I set the Current Directory to my Windows Application. This solved the problem. Thanks a lot again!!!1

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that it's not running from the execution directory.
Use an absolute path and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

[File.Exists docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) talks about the GetCurrentDirectory() and building up an absolute path.